# Type of cached formula value - XSSF event

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

Is there an easy way (i.e. without evaluating the formula) to detect the type of the cached formula value. Here is an example of a formula cell element:

```
<c r="N4" t="str">
  <f>CONCATENATE("3",".","5")</f>
  <v>3.5</v>
</c>
```

Here the type should be STRING and not NUMBER.

Comment: Does `t="str"` not tell you it's a string then?

Comment: @Gagravarr str indicates that it is a formula. It is misleading.

Comment: If you create a formula cell with a numeric answer of 3.5 (eg `=7/2`), what do you get then? (Maybe update the question with that?)

Comment: @Gagravarr simple formulas are treated differently (a bit like how a C or java compiler would do), the cell is not marked as "str" (formula) but the formula element "f" is kept. I am not interested in this cas as I know how to handle it.

Comment: Did you try looking at the logic used in the XSSF UserModel? specifically [XSSFCell](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.java) method `getCachedFormulaResultType`